# Развертывание Django проекта с помощью nginx и uwsgi

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Делаю в соответствии с [документацией](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html). Установить uwsgi и nginx получилось. Скачала файл `uwsgi_params`, создала файл `mysite_nginx.conf`

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
# server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
# the port your site will be served on
listen      8000;
# the domain name it will serve for
server_name localhost; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
charset     utf-8;

# max upload size
client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

# Django media
location /media  {
    alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/mysite/friends_plans/media;  # your Django   project's media files - amend as required
}

location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/myproject/mysite/friends_plans/static; # your Django   project's static files - amend as required
}

# Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /home/ubuntu/myproject/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the    uwsgi_params file you installed
}
}
```

Выполнила команды

```
$ sudo ln -s ~/path/to/your/mysite/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
$ python manage.py collectstatic
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Пробую зайти в браузере `localhost:8000` , появляется надпись "Unable to connect. Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8000...".

С использованием 80 порта появляется приветсвие nginx. Посмотреть файл с логами не получается. Выполняла команду `/var/log/nginx/error.log` , сначала ответом было "permission denied", я много чего пробовала, в итоге теперь "file busy". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так и что нужно сделать, чтобы сервер запустился?
Заранее большое спасибо!

```
(myvenv) ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/myproject/mysite$ sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP -  sTCP:LISTEN
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dnsmasq 1039   nobody    5u  IPv4  15044      0t0  TCP 127.0.1.1:53 (LISTEN)
mysqld  1068    mysql   21u  IPv4  16409      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306   (LISTEN)
java    2285   ubuntu  142u  IPv4  21541      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6942 (LISTEN)
java    2285   ubuntu  203u  IPv4  22124      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:63342 (LISTEN)
cupsd   2627     root   10u  IPv6  24962      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd   2627     root   11u  IPv4  24963      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
nginx   4230     root    6u  IPv4  53589      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   4230     root    7u  IPv6  53590      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   4231 www-data    6u  IPv4  53589      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   4231 www-data    7u  IPv6  53590      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   4232 www-data    6u  IPv4  53589      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   4232 www-data    7u  IPv6  53590      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   4233 www-data    6u  IPv4  53589      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   4233 www-data    7u  IPv6  53590      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   4234 www-data    6u  IPv4  53589      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   4234 www-data    7u  IPv6  53590      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
(myvenv) ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/myproject/mysite$


(myvenv) ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/myproject/mysite$ service uwsgi status
&#9679; uwsgi.service - LSB: Start/stop uWSGI server instance(s)
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/uwsgi)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-06-03 03:26:09 EDT; 1 day   3h ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 1313 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/uwsgi start (code=exited, status=127)

Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/stop   uWSGI....
Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox uwsgi[1313]: /etc/init.d/uwsgi: line 72: /...y
Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox uwsgi[1313]: /etc/init.d/uwsgi: line 73: /...y
Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox uwsgi[1313]: * Starting app server(s) uwsgi
Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox uwsgi[1313]: /etc/init.d/uwsgi: line 80: d...d
Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox uwsgi[1313]: ...fail!
Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: control process...7
Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start/sto....
Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi.service entered fai....
Jun 03 03:26:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: uwsgi.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` что выдаёт? Для чтения логов используйте `sudo less /var/log/nginx/error.log` (выход кнопкой q)

Comment: Андрей, `sudo nginx -t` выдает `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok` `nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is sucsessful`

Comment: Страннота, а `sudo ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`? Там должен присутствовать `mysite_nginx.conf`, а если его нет — значит `ln -s` не выполнился

Comment: При запуске команды `sudo less /var/log/nginx/error.log` в первый раз было много строк с одним только символом ~ (но это, возможно, потому что я еще не пробовала зайти в браузере на localhost:8000), теперь каждый раз при запуске выдается `sudo less /var/log/nginx/error.log (END)`

Comment: По команде `sudo ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` выдается `default mysite_nginx.conf`

Comment: Такой вывод less означает что файл пустой, что есть хорошо :) А вот то, что 8000 порт не открывается даже после `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`, не есть хорошо, и, увы, пока не могу понять почему

Comment: Ясно, спасибо! Если вдруг появятся идеи по этому поводу, напишите, пожалуйста!

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса вывод команды `sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Александр, добавила!

Comment: Хм-хм, а если `cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite_nginx.conf` — оно выведет содержимое файла или выдаст ошибку? Если ошибку, значит в `ln -s` опечатались

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. конфигурационные файлы должны находиться не в вашем домашнем каталоге, а в каталоге `/etc/nginx` и/или его подкаталогах. поэтому:

   1. скопируйте ваш «сайтовы» файл в полагающееся для него место:

      ```
      $ sudo cp ~/path/to/your/mysite/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/
      ```
   2. создайте символическую ссылку (*symlink*) на этот файл в каталоге «включенных» сайтов:

      ```
      $ sudo ln -sf ../sites-available/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
      ```
2. в пакет [*nginx-common*, конечно же, входит](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/nginx-common/filelist) нормальный дистрибутивный файл `uwsgi_params`. использовать какой-то «левый», да ещё и чёрт знает где расположенный — не имеет смысла. поэтому рекомендую заменить строку:

   ```
   include /home/ubuntu/myproject/mysite/uwsgi_params;
   ```

   на:

   ```
   include uwsgi_params;
   ```
3. как обычно после внесения изменений в конфигурацию, её имеет смысл проверить (средствами самой программы *nginx*):

   ```
   $ sudo service nginx configtest
   ```

   если команда вернёт что-то вроде:

   ```
   [ ok ] Testing nginx configuration:.
   ```

   значит, конфигурация в порядке. если получите что-то иное, приложите это к вопросу — поможем разобраться и устранить ошибки.
4. если проверка конфигурации прошла успешно, перезапустите программу *nginx*:

   ```
   $ sudo service nginx restart
   ```
5. после этого в выводе предложенной мной команды:

   ```
   $ sudo lsof -Pn -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
   ```

   вы должны увидеть процессы *nginx*, слушающие не только 80-й порт (`TCP *:80 (LISTEN)`), но и указанный вами 8000-й (`TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)`).

   если не увидите, приложите к вопросу вывод команды:

   ```
   $ sudo service nginx status
   ```
6. в конфигурации *nginx*-а у вас указано перенаправлять обращения на адрес `127.0.0.1`, порт `8001`. но в приложенном вами выводе программы *lsof* я не наблюдаю ни одного процесса, слушающего этот порт. насколько я понимаю, в руководстве, ссылку на который вы привели, этим должен заниматься некий скрипт `manage.py`, запущенный то ли таким:

   ```
   $ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
   ```

   то ли таким образом:

   ```
   $ uwsgi --http :8001 --module mysite.wsgi
   ```
7. > Выполняла команду /var/log/nginx/error.log

   это не команда. это текстовый файл, который можно просмотреть с помощью, например, программы *less*:

   ```
   $ less /var/log/nginx/error.log
   ```

Comment: Всё написанное бессмысленно, если nginx тупо не хочет слушать порт 8000

Comment: @andreymal, возможно. план по локализации проблемы: 1. анализ содержимого `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. 2. выяснение, что за программа под именем *nginx* работает в системе: возможно, это совсем не та программа, что была установлена в составе пакета *nginx-...*. // это будут следующие вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! После проделанных операций сервер теперь слушает 8000 порт. Но когда я пробую зайти в браузере на страницу localhost:8000 выдается ошибка 502 Bad Gateway. С ней пока тоже не получается разобраться. Но, если я правильно поняла, эт связано не с nginx, а скорее всего с uwsgi.

Comment: Вообще у меня по команде `python manage.py runserver` проект открывается по адресу `127.0.0.1:8000/application_name/...` Наверно, 8001 для uwsgi.

Comment: В файле с логами `[error] 4624#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1", host: "localhost:8000"`. Если вводила какой-то адрес страницы своего проекта та же ошибка, но только в файле с логами GET запрос соответствующий.

Comment: Ага, потому что надо uwsgi запустить

Comment: Я, кажется, запустила `uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi`, но `service uwsgi status` выдает ошибки (я добавила вывод команды в текст вопроса)

Comment: Командой `service uwsgi start` тоже не получалось запустить. В первый раз выдавалось `Failed to start uwsgi.service: Connection timed out` , потом `Job for uwsgi.service failed. See "systemctl status uwsgi.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`. При этом выдается примерно то же самое, что при `service uwsgi status`

Comment: @AnastasiaNovikova, вы как-то определитесь, кто у вас будет слушать 8000-й порт — nginx или uwsgi.

Comment: @AnastasiaNovikova и как-то определитесь, вручную вы запускаете uwsgi или через service, всё-таки это разные вещи

Comment: Андрей, я не совсем понимаю, что значит вручную. Если я правильно поняла пример в документации (и в некоторых аналогичных источниках), то uwsgi еще раз запускать не нужно (после nginx), а когда я перехожу на стараницу `localhost:8000`, должно произойти соединение. В примере для проверки рекомендуется поместить в папку media изображение, и при `localhost:8000/media/picture.jpg` должно появиться это изображение

Comment: Александр, с `uwsgi --http :8001 --module mysite.wsgi` тоже не получается

Comment: Я перезапустила uwsgi `service uwsgi stop` , `uwsgi --http :8001 --module mysite.wsgi`. Теперь проверка с изображением `localhost:8000/media/name.jpg` пройдена! Спасибо большое за помощь! Надеюсь, дальше все тоже получиться.